# Parsing the nested XML fields from PySpark Dataframe using UDF

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a scenario where I have XML data in a dataframe column.

| sex | updated_at | visitors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F | 1574264158 | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8 |

I want to parse - Visitors column - the nested XML fields into columns in Dataframe using UDF

Format of XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <visitors> <visitor id="9615" age="68" sex="F" /> <visitor id="1882" age="34" sex="M" /> <visitor id="5987" age="23" sex="M" /> </visitors>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `xpath` queries without using UDFs:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <visitors> <visitor id="9615" age="68" sex="F" /> <visitor id="1882" age="34" sex="M" /> <visitor id="5987" age="23" sex="M" /> </visitors>']], ['visitors'])

df.show(truncate=False)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|visitors                                                                                                                                                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <visitors> <visitor id="9615" age="68" sex="F" /> <visitor id="1882" age="34" sex="M" /> <visitor id="5987" age="23" sex="M" /> </visitors>|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


df2 = df.selectExpr(
    "xpath(visitors, './visitors/visitor/@id') id",
    "xpath(visitors, './visitors/visitor/@age') age",
    "xpath(visitors, './visitors/visitor/@sex') sex"
).selectExpr(
    "explode(arrays_zip(id, age, sex)) visitors"
).select('visitors.*')

df2.show(truncate=False)
+----+---+---+
|id  |age|sex|
+----+---+---+
|9615|68 |F  |
|1882|34 |M  |
|5987|23 |M  |
+----+---+---+
```

If you insist on using UDFs:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

@F.udf('array<struct<id:string, age:string, sex:string>>')
def parse_xml(s):
    root = ET.fromstring(s)
    return list(map(lambda x: x.attrib, root.findall('visitor')))
    
df2 = df.select(
    F.explode(parse_xml('visitors')).alias('visitors')
).select('visitors.*')

df2.show()
+----+---+---+
|  id|age|sex|
+----+---+---+
|9615| 68|  F|
|1882| 34|  M|
|5987| 23|  M|
+----+---+---+
```

Comment: @Mr.Tssou It's possible, but due to performance reasons, UDF is not recommended when the task can be achieved using Spark SQL functions

Comment: if it's possible can you do it please ? cuz i want to see other approaches without using xpath

Comment: @Mr.Tssou see my edited answer for a UDF solution.